# QSqlQuery Insert into database doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

I use `PyQt4.QtSql.QSqlQuery`. I get values from a Form and want to Insert them into the database. I open a connection and try to Add, but there are no values in the database and no errors. What's the problem?

```
    db      = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")

    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setDatabaseName("vista")
    db.setUserName("root")
    db.setPassword("secret")

    if (db.open()==False):     
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error",
            db.lastError().text())   
    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO user (fio, sex,polis,document,birtday) "
      "VALUES (:fio, :sex,:polis,:document,:birtday)");
    query.bindValue(":fio", fio);
    query.bindValue(":sex", sex);
    query.bindValue(":polis", polis);
    query.bindValue(":document", document);
    query.bindValue(":birtday", birtday);
    query.exec_();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must [commit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#commit) the changes you have made:

```
if query.exec_():
    db.commit() 
else:
    QMessageBox.warning(None, "Database Error",
        query.lastError().text())
```